Can I change what width LWC / SLDS considers a small-device-size?
I want to use lightning-layout and lightning-layout-item to render some items in either one or two columns.  But I want it to go to the one column in a slightly larger container.  When I have the item in a sidebar of a lightning page, it's larger than what it considers small so it still goes to two columns but I want one.  I don't know what the pixel size is when it considers the container small, likely something around phone size, maybe around 300px.  But I want it to use small and go to one column when the container is maybe 400 or 500px.  Any way to change the definition of what it considers small device?
<lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="12" large-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
    <div class="slds-form-element formEl">
        <lightning-output-field field-name={fieldName}></lightning-output-field>            
    </div>    
</lightning-layout-item>


I should add that since I have small and medium set to 12 and only large set to 6, I would think it isn't even going to medium when rendered in a sidebar.

I found a reference that says small is 480px or higher, medium is 768px or higher, and large is 1024px or higher.  SInce I have medium as 12 and my container is 553px, I would think I should be getting one column but I'm getting two.  I need to make the window unrealistically narrower to get one.

The sizing is based on screen width not container width, unfortunately.

I'd recommend just using the SLDS classes yourself rather than the components for this: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/
As you can see, the html behind these components isn't really any more verbose than the components. And you could override the behavior of the classes scoped to the component.
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
  <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2">
    testing
  </div>
  <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2">
    testing 2
  </div>
</div>

I'd like to point out that the sizing is mobile-first, meaning that the default size (with no screen size selector) bubbles up to large screens, meaning that you only need to override the default sizing for larger displays that need a different sizing.

I tried something like that but with the component in the main part of the page, I still get only one column even though the container is 1097px.  Is there something else I need to do to set what it considers large?

If you want to know if your component has been put in the main region of a flexi page or in a sidebar, you need to declare a public flexipageRegionWidth property and the framework will set either SMALL, MEDIUM, and LARGE based on the different region widths.
Then you need to define few getters to expose boolean property which will let you render some elements conditionally via lwc:if|elseif|else={property} directive in your template.
JS
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class WidthAwareComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api flexipageRegionWidth;
    
    get isSmallRegion() {
        return 'SMALL' === this.flexipageRegionWidth;
    }

    get isMediumRegion() {
        return 'MEDIUM' === this.flexipageRegionWidth;
    }
}

HTML
<template>
    <p lwc:if={isSmallRegion}>I'm in a small region, like a sidebar</p>
    <p lwc:elseif={isMediumRegion}>I'm in a medium region</p>
    <p lwc:else>I'm in a large region</p>
</template>


